# exponentiation RSA

Tags: c++, rsa

I am trying to implement RSA in C++ for extremely large numbers. I am not using any library. I wanted to write my own code :) So I have used strings to store these large numbers. Multiplication and division of large numbers is extremely quick so thats not a problem. But when i do encrypting or decrypting i.e using a^b modm this is extremely slow. I used p and q as 50 digits numbers and tried encrypting a text of about 20 characters. It took me one hour to encrypt and decrypt. I used exponentiation by squaring method to reduce the computational time. What possible improvement can i do?

Also what is the best way to generate primes p & q.(Preferably industry standard)

Comment: If this is for anything other than learning how to (not) implement RSA, stop, and use a well-tested high-level library.

Comment: RSA is known to be a slow method, that's why RSA is used mostly to transmit a session key for a faster, shared key, method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing the modular reduction after after squaring/multiplication during your exponentiation? You should calculate the modulus after each squaring/multiplication so the intermediate results should never be more than twice the digits as in your value for m.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll bet that is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think that arbitrary precision arithmetic libraries like e.g. [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) contains some very carefully tuned functions (and even some handcrafted assember code).

And multi-precision arithmetic algorithms are very complex (and not very intuitive). There are books on that subject (I've borrowed one once, it was too difficult to grasp in all the details, unless you spend a lot of hours studying the math inside).

If I where you, I would use some existing library like GMP.

Or else, take the time to study, read and learn the hard math.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, if you want RSA in something you're writing, you should use a well tested library rather than your own code. However, writing code can be very helpful to learn things, so there is absolutely nothing wrong with doing that.

1. What i'd guess is slowing you down is the computation of a^b in a^b mod m, because a^b is going to be an extremely huge number. Using squares to compute this helps the runtime somewhat, but you still end up with huge intermediate numbers and a huge result, before taking the modulus. There are a lot of tricks to performing modular exponentiation more quickly, but wikipedia has a better knowledge of them than I do:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation . I'd look there first.
2. I don't know anything about the industry state of RSA, so this is just a push in hopefully the right direction: since prime testing is generally slow, for p and q you probably want "probable primes": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_prime
3. Strings sound like a rather inefficient way to do this. If #1 doesn't help, you might want to look into java's BigInteger library, and either find an equivalent in C++, or write your own. This would only provide a constant factor of speed and memory usage improvement, however (unless examining the code shows you a better algorithm for something you are performing), so it might not be worth the time to write your own. Adopting someone else's might still be worthwhile though.